# How to display static analysis warnings in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, warnings, static-analysis, remote-execution

I've noticed the MATLAB editor will often show quite helpful warnings for ".m" files. As I tend to run my MATLAB code remotely I prefer not to use the MATLAB editor, instead keeping open a long running emacs session. It would be great if these warnings could be printed out when running a script, perhaps if some setting was enabled (I could imagine not wanting to do that by default for performance). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`checkcode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html). From the documentation:

> `checkcode(filename)` displays messages about `filename` that report potential problems and opportunities for code improvement. These messages are sometimes referred to as Code Analyzer messages. The line number in the message is a hyperlink that you can click to go directly to that line in the Editor. The exact text of the `checkcode` messages is subject to some change between versions.
>
> ...
>
> `info = checkcode(___,'-struct')` returns the information as an `n`-by-`1` structure array, where `n` is the number of messages found.